# How prove this Nice inequality $\sum\limits_\text{cyc}\frac{x^2}{y}\ge 3+\frac{x^4+y^4+z^4-x^2-y^2-z^2}{x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, buffalo-way

**Question:**

> let $x,y,z>0$, show that
>   $$\dfrac{x^2}{y}+\dfrac{y^2}{z}+\dfrac{z^2}{x}\ge 3+\dfrac{x^4+y^4+z^4-x^2-y^2-z^2}{x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz}$$

I know this well know inequality
$$\dfrac{x^2}{y}+\dfrac{y^2}{z}+\dfrac{z^2}{x}\ge \dfrac{37(x^2+y^2+z^2)-19(x+y+z)}{6(x+y+z)}$$

I found this inequality is stronger, and I can't prove it

Comment: What happens when you multiply by the (positive) xyz(x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz) and cancel terms? That'll make the problem uglier, but eventually will either solve it or reduce it to something easier.

Comment: Your well-known inequality doesn't hold at $x=y=z=2$

Comment: It should be $\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\geq\frac{37(x^2+y^2+z^2)-19(xy+xz+yz)}{6(x+y+z)}$

Answer (score 1):

BW helps.

We need to prove that
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\right)(x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz)-x^4-y^4-z^4+x^2+y^2+z^2\geq$$
$$\geq3(x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz).$$
Now, by AM-GM
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\right)(x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz)-x^4-y^4-z^4+x^2+y^2+z^2\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\right)(x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz)-x^4-y^4-z^4\right)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$4\left(\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\right)(x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz)-x^4-y^4-z^4\right)(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq$$
$$\geq9(x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz)^2.$$
Let $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$, $y=x+u$, $z=x+v$ and $u=kv$.

Hence, 
$$4xyz\left(\left(\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\right)(x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz)-x^4-y^4-z^4\right)(x^2+y^2+z^2)-$$
$$-9xyz(x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz)^2=$$
$$=8(u^2-uv+v^2)x^7-8uv(u-8v)x^6+3(5u^4-34u^3v+71u^2v^2+14uv^3+5v^4)x^5+$$
$$+(21u^5-125u^4v+201u^3v^2+121u^2v^3+95uv^4+21v^5)x^4+$$
$$+(29u^6-141u^5v+238u^4v^2-29u^3v^3+198u^2v^4+51uv^5+29v^6)x^3+$$
$$+(19u^7-75u^6v+114u^5v^2+12u^4v^3+52u^3v^4+90u^2v^5+29uv^6+19v^7)x^2+$$
$$+(4u^8-13u^7v+16u^6v^2+24u^5v^3-2u^4v^4+40u^3v^5+8u^2v^6+19uv^7+4u^8)x+$$
$$+4uv^3(u^5+u^3v^2+u^2v^3+v^5)\geq$$
$$=8(u^2-uv+v^2)x^7-8uv(u-8v)x^6+3(5u^4-34u^3v+71u^2v^2+14uv^3+5v^4)x^5\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{24x^{12}(u^2-uv+v^2)(5u^4-34u^3v+71u^2v^2+14uv^3+5v^4)}-8uv(u-8v)x^6.$$
Id est, it remains to prove that
$$3(k^2-k+1)(5k^4-34k^3+71k^2+14k+5)\geq2k^2(k-8)^2$$ or
$$15k^6-117k^5+328k^4-241k^3+58k^2+27k+15\geq0,$$
which is  true:
$$15k^6-117k^5+328k^4-241k^3+58k^2+27k+15>$$
$$>k^2(15k^4-117k^3+328k^2-241k+58)=$$
$$=15\left(k^2-\frac{117}{30}k+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{20}(1097k^2-1310k+485)>0$$ and we are done!

Comment: What is BW? Why the last inequality is obviously true? Could you pleas add a bit of explanations on how you found this solution?

Comment: @Thomas BW=Buffalo Way. It's the method, which I used. See also here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h522084

Comment: Thanks for the link !

Comment: @Thomas I added something again. See now.

Comment: There is an a in the buffalo substitution which looks like a typo. Maybe is it an x? And are you supposing x<y<z (and k>1) ?

Comment: @Thomas No. I assumed $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$ and $u=kv$. In the writing $z=a+v$ was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Yes anyway the sum on the left is a cycling so one cannot assume (without justification) x<y<z and k>1. At a certain point you write $15k^6-117k^5+328k^4-241k^3+58k^2+27k+15=
(15k^6-117k^5+229k^4)+199k^4-255k^3+58k^2+27k+15$. Are you sure there are not typos there? I cannot match the coefficients of $k^4$  and $k^3$ could you tell me if there are typos or if I do not see that?

Comment: ( I think you have k>0 instead from the BW ? )

Comment: @Thomas I have fixed my mistake. See now. I used  $k>0$ only.

Comment: Ok thanks. One remaining question. Why did you apply first AM-GM and than BW ? What suggested you to apply AM-GM before?

Comment: @Thomas Because it leads to the homogeneous inequality.

Comment: Perfect thanks!